# What does Django use as a Cache Key?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I'm caching Wagtail API endpoints using Django's standard `cache_page` function which looks something like this:

```
@method_decorator(cache_page(600), name="detail_view")
@method_decorator(cache_page(600), name="listing_view")
class CashedPagesAPIViewSet(PagesAPIViewSet):
    """Custom API endpoint that can receive a slug."""

    pass
```

Very basic.

I want to be able to clear the API cache on each page save, but I don't know how to get the cache key.

I can clear all the cache with this:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from wagtail.core.signals import page_published


def clear_cache(sender, **kwargs):
    """Clear page cache."""
    cache.clear()


page_published.connect(clear_cache)
```

What I want to be able to do is:

```
def clear_cache(sender, **kwargs):
    """Clear page cache."""
    page = kwargs["instance"]
    cache.delete(f"/api/v2/pages/{page.id}") # or whatever the key might be
```